# groupby object to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for a function to make a transformation

```
sys_task_id   timestamp
    a_b       2017-11-01
    a_b       2018-02-01
    c_b       2018-02-01
```

from above to below

```
sys_task_id   timestamp
    a_b       [2017-11-01, 2018-02-01]
    c_b       [2018-02-01]
```

clearly, I should group by `sys_task_id`, then how?

Comment: `df.groupby('sys_task_id').timestamp.apply(list)`

Comment: @QuangHoang You help me again!

Comment: @QuangHoang Please make this into a proper answer with some notations.  I haven't seen this type of aggregation method with groupby and I think it could be a beneficial answer to the community. Thanks and best regards.